# Did 5.8 kernel drop support for BCM43224 wireless?

Tags: wireless, kernel

Just got the 5.8.0-34 kernel update, and wireless doesn't work with the BCM43224 wireless in this old DELL zino HD mini-pc. It worked fine when I first installed 20.04 with no magic required, and it works fine if I reboot into the older 5.4.0-59 kernel I had previously. Has ubuntu dropped support for this, or is it a kernel/build bug?

Here is the relevant lshw from the 5.8 kernel:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
```

In the 5.4 kernel I see this:

```
  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: c0:cb:38:27:23:c0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:fe8fc000-fe8fffff
```

So it looks like the driver is gone, but I didn't do anything to install that driver when I installed 20.04, it just worked out of the box.

Comment: When you boot into 5.4.0-59 what is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`?  Add the output to your question.  It's possible a driver might need to be installed for the 5.8 kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With better things to search for, I found this:

[bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1906745/comments/1)

The suggestion in the linked comment worked.